# Geometric Proof of $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b )$ and its applications

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I am teaching a student on the subject of factoring. One commonly used formula is $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b) $. It is easy to prove it from RHS to LHS algebraically, but how to prove it geometrically? I would also like to find some of its applications, such as this:$(\sin\theta)^2+(\cos\theta)^2=( \cos \theta +i\sin \theta)(\cos\theta -i\sin \theta )=e^{i\theta}\cdot e^{-i\theta  } =e^0=1$

Are there any other good examples?

**EDIT:** some comments for applications

(Albus) $\frac{1}{\sqrt a+b}=\frac{\sqrt a-b}{a-b^2}$

(Paul) $a\times b=(\frac{a+b}{2})^2-(\frac{a-b}{2})^2$

(other ) $x=x’+y’, y=x’-y’, xy=x’^2-y’^2=1$ Hyperbola  equation

Comment: One application that comes to my mind is *rationalising the denominator*

Comment: $(27)(23) = 25^2-2^2=621$ and similar is always handy.

Comment: This may be of some use  - https://www.mathdoubts.com/a-squared-minus-b-squared-geometric-proof/

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, you could compute the area between two enclosing squares maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$a^2 - b^2 =  (a-b)b + (a-b)b + (a-b)^2 $$
$$ = (a-b)[b + b + (a-b)] $$

or

$$a^2 - b^2 =  (a-b)a + (a-b)b$$
$$ = (a-b)(a+ b) $$

Draw two squares inside each other ($a>b$) and look at the three or two leftover rectangular areas.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Here is one example I can think of. Ask the student to calculate the area of the yellow zone in the above figure: the area between two squares with sides $a$ and $b$ . It must be easy for the student to obtain the result by subtracting the areas of the two squares:
$$S_{yellowZone} = a^2 - b^2 \qquad (1)$$

But we can also calculate the area as the sum of areas of two narrow rectangles $EBHF$ and $GHCD$ :
$$S_{EBHF} = EB \times EF = (a-b).b$$
$$S_{GHCD} = GD \times GH = (a-b).a$$
Adding up these two we calculate the yellow zone area, which we had previously found to be $a^2 - b^2$:
$$S_{yellowZone} = (a-b).b + (a-b).a = (a-b)(a+b) \qquad (2)$$
From (1) and (2) we have our proof.

Edit: I just noticed that user973676 suggested this approach too. Credits to them.

So here is another example! Calculate the area of the rectangle $AXYZ$ in the figure below:
[image]

**Update:** One useful application of this identity, in addition to being handy in arithmetic calculations, is that it helps teach students that *if the sum of two numbers is constant, then their product is maximum when the two numbers are equal*.

It also opens a door for teaching the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Thanks, your figure visually shows what $(a-b)(a+b)$ is by attaching it on the top (or bottom) -definitely helpful!.

Comment: @BrightStar Thank you for the compliment!